# Flashback removal tool

Tags: macos, virus

Since there is not so much communication around the flashback virus on MacOSX, I would like to know how to proceed to be sure that my system is clean.

I download the software at this adress and install it: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1517

And now what?

Comment: That update should have been part of your mac update that runs automatically, it should already be applied as part of the normal mac updates. Once applied your system is clean.

Comment: ok I would have liked a little message like "your mac is clean" or something like that...

Comment: I think they only do that in Windows.. ;;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is an excellent guide article here](http://www.mytechguide.org/11766/flashback-trojan-removal-tool/)

Here is a quick walk-through of what you need to do:

- First, [Download the tool directly from Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1517) or use Lion’s inbuilt Software Update to download the tool.
  If you’ve downloaded the tool using the link above, mount the DMG file and launch FlashbackMalwareRemover.pkg. If you’ve used Software Update, the tool will launch itself after download.
- Click on the Continue, click “Install” and enter your OS X Lion administrative password when prompted for.

[image]

- Just wait until the tool repairs your Mac, if its infected.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend [ClamXav](http://www.clamxav.com/download.php), a Mac version of the excellent ClamAntiVirus. This does cover Flashback, and other trojans.

There are two versions available, the standalone download, and the App Store version. Both will remove Flashback. Apple has some restrictions on what apps in the App Store can do, so there is a little bit of functionality loss with the App Store version, but both work well.